# JQuery toggle function for additional item

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this JQuery toggle/collapse function but some reason "timelineEventWide" which I added myself won't work. I'm new to Javascript could you please advice me with correct syntax? Thank you

```
e(".expandAll").toggle(function() {
      n(e(this).parents(t.timelineContainer).find("dt a", "dl.timelineMinor"), e(this).parents(t.timelineContainer).find(".timelineEvent",".timelineEventWide"));
      e(this).html("- collapse all")
      }, function() {
             r(e(this).parents(t.timelineContainer).find("dl.timelineMinor a"), e(this).parents(t.timelineContainer).find(".timelineEvent", ".timelineEventWide"));
             e(this).html("+ expand all")
      })
})
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with jQuery but shouldn't there be a semicolon at the end of each })? e.g. });

Comment: I think e,n,r characters should be changed with $ if there are no special meanings for these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find` only takes one argument.  You probably mean to use

```
.find(".timelineEventWide .timelineEvent")
```

Comment: .find(".timelineEventWide, .timelineEvent")